# Missing libcryptopp.so.6

Tags: 14.04, shared-library

I have an application that I need to run which is telling me that it cannot find libcryptopp.so.6. I have tried installing every package that I could find that has a change of installing it but nothing worked. I even tried making a symlink to libcrypto.so but it did not go for that. I am on Ubuntu 14.04. What do I need to do to get it?

EDIT:
If it makes a difference, I am on a 64bit system and I think the application is compiled for 32bit because I had to install the 32bit version of libusb for it before this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need the libcrypto++-dev package.  Determine this with apt-file

```
$ apt-file search libcryptopp
libcrypto++-dev: /usr/lib/libcryptopp.a
libcrypto++-dev: /usr/lib/libcryptopp.so
libcrypto++9: /usr/lib/libcryptopp.so.9
```

Of course that's the 32 bit version, and you may need a link from the .6 version your app needs to the .9 version.

---

The link for your 32 bit program needs to be added into /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu, not the x86_64-linux-gnu (case is important).  Check what the 32 bit executable needs and sees with ldd.  A properly set up 32 bit set of libraries should have a working ldd which reports on the 32 bit executables.  A system not properly set up will report garbage like "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: Ok I have looked and there is actually already a correct symlink in /usr/lib/x86_64-Linux-gnu but it seems that the application does not see it, what should I do?